# Robust smoothers for geometric multigrid

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, iterative-method, multigrid

I'm searching for robust smoothers for geometric multigrids.

By robust I mean:

- Effective for high order approximations (say spectral element, spectral Discontinuous Galerkin),
- Parallel (suitable for co-processors),
- Effective for heterogeneity and anisotropy problems.

From what I can gather, Schwarz type smoothers may be promising [(Fischer et al)](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~fischer/pubhtml/IP109-frame.pdf); and block/line/ plane, and ILU smoothers are also recommended [(Trottenberg et al)](https://books.google.com/books?id=-og1wD-Nx_wC).

Are there any other state-of-the-art smoothers I should consider?

Comment: Are these for elliptic problems?

Comment: Ideally, elliptic, parabolic, or hyperbolic.  I'm not necessarily looking for a "one size fits all"; i.e. if there is a smoother that is intended only for elliptic problems, this is alright.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomial smoothers as described in M. Adams, M. Brezina, J. Hu, and R. Tuminaro, "Parallel multigrid smoothing: polynomial versus Gauss-Seidel", J. Comp. Physics, vol. 188, pp. 593-610 (2003).

Comment: It would be helpful if a summary of their results were included in your answer.